# Configure CA certs for SSL API call

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, websphere, ca

I am a newbie when it comes to SSL. So I could use some expertise here regarding my situation.

I have a Java based web app that makes SSL API calls. The `API` and web app, both are hosted in the same server (`myserver`), and web app makes API calls. Now for testing purpose, we created a `self signed certificate` with the local domain name and server name (`myserver.mydomain.local)` and added to the `cacerts`. SSL handlshake works as desired.

But now, our client is using a `CA certificate` which they imported to `cacerts`. And during the SSL handshake, the web app client complains that the certificate issued by the

`CN=abc-dns.com,OU=Root Certificate, OU=WASFarmLLLCell01, OU=WASFarmLLLCellManager01, O=IBM, C=US is not trusted;` where `abc-dns.com` is the `server name` where the API is hosted through `Web Sphere`.

Do they need to add a self signed certificate in the trust store with the server name `abc-dns.com` in it to resolve the SSL handshake? Any tips will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public key from abc-dns.com needs to be added to the truststore of the server that is throwing the handshake exception.  There are multiple ways of doing that, here's one: 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/usec_sslretrievesignercert.html

Comment: Yes, ended up adding the key and that worked. Thanks!